# How does the SYSUTCDATETIME SQL Server function behave inside a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

For example:

```
SET @var1 = SYSUTCDATETIME();

...

SET @var2 = SYSUTCDATETIME();

IF @var1 = @var2
    RETURN 0;
ELSE
    RETURN 1;
```

Is it **certain** that I will always get zero, no matter what is in between `var1` and `var2`?

In my view, given a specific release of SQL Server, the answer should be a simple yes/no answer; I'm **not** concerned about the details of the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No, the code between these 2 calls will take some time, so the values will be different.

EDIT: Assuming there is some code between them. In extreme cases, when these 2 assignments are adjacent and the server has nothing else to do, the variables might end up having the same value.

However, separate calls of `sysutcdatetime()` and other similar functions **within the same statement / query** do produce identical values.

Comment: `will be different` should probably be `may be different`, since it entirely depends on the code between the two.

Comment: @ZLK, no, it only depends on the precision with which the measurement is performed :).

Comment: @RogerWolf What ZLK is saying is that if the subsequent calls are made quickly enough, the value will be the same, which is why they **may** be different if the workload in between them took enough time.

Comment: @DavidG, I know :) However, a language in which every statement has to be interpreted and compiled, even two adjacent lines should normally differ in their start and finish times.

Comment: @RogerWolf the point is that you state the *values will be different* which someone may come to rely on at some point, for example using them as a primary key (OK, contrived example, but you get my point!) All ZLK (and now me) is saying is that you need to change it to say that they will likely be different.

Comment: @DavidG, the original question says `Is it certain that I will always get zero` - and my answer "no" is completely correct and to the point. That is - "no, it is not certain".

Comment: Your logic is a bit back to front there. Read the first sentence in your answer, you state that the values WILL be different which is absolutely not true. I don't know how to put it any other way. Your edit improves the post, but it's still flawed. I'll leave it here, I've said my piece, you can do as you wish now.